# How to pass props into a component extracted from a component lookup using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having a problem with typescript when attempting to pass props into and render a component which has been pulled out of a lookup.

The lookup is defined as:

```
type TableElements = {
  row: typeof DocumentRow | typeof ValuationRow;
};

const TableLookup: Record<string, TableElements> = {
  document: {
    row: DocumentRow,
  },
  valuation: {
    row: ValuationRow,
  },
};
```

I then use the tabletype (here it is declared as 'valuation') to pull the row component from the lookup:

```
const tableElements = TableLookup[tableType];
const TableRowComponent = tableElements.row;
```

I then try to render this component with:

```
{rows.map((row) => (
   <TableRowComponent
      rowData={row}
   />
 ))}
```

where "rows" is of type:

```
Array<RowDataType>
```

and RowDataType is of type:

```
type RowDataType = DocumentRowDataType | ValuationRowDataType;
```

but typescript gives me the error:

```
Type 'RowDataType' is not assignable to type 'DocumentRowDataType & ValuationRowDataType'.
```

I'm unsure why the type I am attempting to assign to is 'DocumentRowDataType & ValuationRowDataType'. I was expecting it to be 'DocumentRowDataType | ValuationRowDataType'

both DocumentRow and ValuationRow have a "rowData" prop, with one rowData being of type "DocumentRowDataType" and the other being "ValuationRowDataType".

"rows" is an array of RowDataType ('DocumentRowDataType | ValuationRowDataType') and each element of rows is assigned to either a DocumentRow or ValuationRow's rowData prop which can be either DocumentRowDataType or ValuationRowDataType, so I'm unsure why typescript isn't happy with this?

Would very much appreciate some help if anyone notices something I am missing, or if I'm misunderstanding something

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested in this, I managed to fix this by explicitly giving a type to the TableRowComponent:

```
const TableRowComponent = tableElements.row as React.ComponentType<{
    rowData: RowDataType;
}>;
```